# unable to download html using html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to download webpage html using html agility pack

```
HtmlWeb webpage = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument webdoc = webpage.Load("http://www.ravnikinteriordesign.com/");
var htmlresult = webdoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

but it only returns this

```
<html> <head><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://ravnikandco.com">  </head> </html>
```

instead of returning the entire html of the website.
Can someone please help me with this? I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tag means that the site will redirect to http://ravnikandco.com

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://ravnikandco.com">
```

Change your code to this:

```
HtmlWeb webpage = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument webdoc = webpage.Load("http://ravnikandco.com/");
var htmlresult = webdoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
```

Comment: oh I am so dumb but thank you so much. This is great help